# Chained Methods OOP call_user_func_array php

Tags: php, oop, chained

I was wondering if the following is possible. We have a class that is design to used chained methods.

```
$CarClass = $CarConnection->models->count();
```

In the above example we are counting the models. However, want to do it dynamically. So for instance:

```
$CountArray = array('models','brands','countries');
foreach($CountArray AS $key => $value){
    $CarData[$value] = $CarConnection->$value->count();       
}
```

However, this outputs an error: "Call to a member function count() on a non-object in" While i'm pretty sure the count exists as the earlier mention function is working.

Some googling led to add brackets { } but that doesn't work either.

```
 $CarData[$value] = $CarConnection->{$value}->count();
```

Any one a solution?

Kind regards,

Peter

Comment: Looks like you are getting null (or any other result except object) while you are trying to access one of the properties (models, brands, or countries) or magic method (if any) __get of the $CarConnection class does not return the object. The call $CarConnection->{$value}->count();  is correct.

Comment: Make sure `$CarConnection` has the `model`, `brands` and `countries` properties and they are objects that expose the `count()` method. The error message say you are calling `count()` on a value that is not an object. It may be `NULL` or something else (array, string, integer etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can spot a syntax error in your loop:
It should go -

```
$CountArray = array('models','brands','countries');

foreach($CountArray as $key => $value){
$CarData[$value] = $CarConnection->$value->count();
```

}

And also, the array you have is not an associative one. So you don't need $key!
Try this:

```
foreach($CountArray as $value) {
 $CarData[$value] = $CarConnection->{$value}->count();
}
```

Comment: With the syntax error changed, the error remains. (Corrected in the Answer).